# No se ejecuta el código en visual studio

Tags: python

Las extensiones están instaladas; también los paquetes  de matplotlib, así como los scripts para el entorno virtual

```
 import time
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     import random
     piezas = {"A" : 0, "B" : 0, "C" : 0, "D" : 0,}
     total_piezas = 0
     lotes = {"A" : 0, "B" : 0, "C" : 0, "D" : 0,}
     total_lotes = 0
     
     def producir_pieza(tipo_pieza):
         global piezas, total_piezas,lotes, total_lotes
         if tipo_pieza in piezas:
             piezas[tipo_pieza] +=1
             total_piezas += 1
             print(f"Se produjo una pieza de tipo {tipo_pieza}.") 
             if piezas[tipo_pieza] % 5 ==0:
                print(f"LOTE DEL PRODUCTO {tipo_pieza} TERMINADO")
                 lotes[tipo_pieza] += 1
                 total_lotes += 1
                 if total_lotes % 10 == 0:
                  mostrár_grafíca_lotes()
                 if total_piezas % 20 == 0:
                         print("ESTACIóN EN MANTENIMIENTO")
                         return True
                 else:
                         print("Tipo de pieza no valido.")
                         return False
                 
     def mostrár_grafíca_lotes():
                         plt.bar(lotes.keys(), lotes.values()) 
                         plt.title("Producción de lotes")
                         plt.xlabel("Tipo de producto")
                         plt.ylabel("Numero de lotes")
                         plt.show()
                         while True:
                             tipo_pieza = input("Que pieza requiere? (A/B/C/D.)")
                             if tipo_pieza in piezas:
                                 producir_pieza(tipo_pieza)
                             else:
                                 print("Tipo de pieza no valido.")
                                 time.sleep(20)
                                 print("ESTACIóN EN MANTENIMIENTO")
```

Comment: puedes compartir el error que te genera o que comportamiento tiene?

Comment: Te falta llamar a la función `mostrár_grafíca_lotes()`, porque la magia de `Python` no da para tanto...

Answer (score 0):

Yo veo que tienes problemas de identación ese puede ser uno de tus problemas.

```
import time 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import random 
piezas = {"A" : 0, "B" : 0, "C" : 0, "D" : 0,} 
total_piezas = 0 
lotes = {"A" : 0, "B" : 0, "C" : 0, "D" : 0,} 
total_lotes = 0

def producir_pieza(tipo_pieza):
    global piezas, total_piezas,lotes, total_lotes
    if tipo_pieza in piezas:
        piezas[tipo_pieza] +=1
        total_piezas += 1
        print(f"Se produjo una pieza de tipo {tipo_pieza}.") 
        if piezas[tipo_pieza] % 5 ==0:
            print(f"LOTE DEL PRODUCTO {tipo_pieza} TERMINADO")
            lotes[tipo_pieza] += 1
            total_lotes += 1
            if total_lotes % 10 == 0:
                mostrár_grafíca_lotes()
            if total_piezas % 20 == 0:
                print("ESTACIóN EN MANTENIMIENTO")
                return True
            else:
                print("Tipo de pieza no valido.")
                return False

def mostrar_grafíca_lotes():
    plt.bar(lotes.keys(), lotes.values()) 
    plt.title("Producción de lotes")
    plt.xlabel("Tipo de producto")
    plt.ylabel("Numero de lotes")
    plt.show()
    while True:
        tipo_pieza = input("Que pieza requiere? (A/B/C/D.)")
        if tipo_pieza in piezas:
            producir_pieza(tipo_pieza)
        else:
            print("Tipo de pieza no valido.")
            time.sleep(20)
            print("ESTACIóN EN MANTENIMIENTO")
```

Si te marca algo relacionado con la codificación utf-8, en mi caso lo resolví guardando el archivo con codificación, la cual puedes guardar dando en el menú archivo-guardar como, y en el botón guardar podrás encontrar la opción de guardar con codificación, selecciona unicode utf-8

Saludos.